# How can I load a <div> from a different file into my page

Tags: html, css, resources, external

I want my page to have a navigation menu, but I don't want to copy and paste it to every webpage every time I update it, so I'm trying to put it in a separate file and load it into a div

Comment: Which language you're using.?

Comment: there are a few ways to tackle this, mainly with templating .. knowing which language you are using will help

Comment: In jQuery thats possible with load(): http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: It's all html and css I think. I'm not really all that familiar with web dev, so I think js works too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**w3-include**](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or [**PHP**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp):

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="menu">
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
</div>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

There are other ways too, I just included two.

Comment: this works great and is easy to implement, thank you!

Comment: @Zachary: Doesn't this load the entire html page? In your question you asked about loading only one `div` of the page...

Comment: @TheodoreK. You can create a html file with just a `div` inside it

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a php file and insert your code there.

**For example:**

In your main file insert this:

```
<div class="container">
<?php require 'example.php';?>
</div>
```

In your "example.php" file insert this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to do in plain html without php?

Answer (score 1):

In `jQuery` you can use `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )` function.
[For more detail click here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

As you describe it you don't want to load the whole page but just one div from it. That's not possible with plain javascript as far as I know. So, I would suggest to put this div in a separate html file (let's call it common.html) and then load it in each page. This can be achieved this way:

```
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="common.html" ></object>';
```